# Is there anyone on Earth who knows how to get Google Drive REST v3 working with apps?

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I've spent hundreds of hours trying to create an Android app that will allow me to open and edit files stored in my Google Drive account, with no success.  I believe I know what to do with the files once I have a DriveService object, but I simply cannot get my head around the credentials, tokens, and authorization.  All documentation and examples are either out of date, too confusing or simply don't work for me.

My latest attempt was to use the Google API sample at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/tasks-android-sample, but the app crashes immediately upon picking the required account.  Can someone please advise what is wrong with my code, or alternatively is there an easier way to get access to a DriveService object for my account?  My MainActivity is as follows (the other classes should be the same as the sample on GitHub).

```
package com.example.googledrivetestapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.tasks.TasksScopes;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import android.os.AsyncTask;


public final class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final Level LOGGING_LEVEL = Level.OFF;

    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";

    static final String TAG = "GoogleDriveTestApp";

    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 0;

    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 2;

    final HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

    final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleAccountCredential credential;

    List<String> tasksList;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks service;

    int numAsyncTasks;

    private ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnChooseAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseAccount);
        btnChooseAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chooseAccount();
            }
        });

        // enable logging
        Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client").setLevel(LOGGING_LEVEL);
        // Google Accounts
        credential =
                GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(TasksScopes.TASKS));
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
        // Tasks client
        service =
                new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                        .setApplicationName("GoogleDriveTestApp").build();

    }

    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(final int connectionStatusCode) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog dialog =
                        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode, MainActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    void refreshView() {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tasksList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            haveGooglePlayServices();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    haveGooglePlayServices();
                } else {
                    checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
                } else {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.commit();
                        AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /** Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. */
    private boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void haveGooglePlayServices() {
        // check if there is already an account selected
        if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            // ask user to choose account
            chooseAccount();
        } else {
            // load calendars
            AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
        }
    }

    private void chooseAccount() {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()  // For google-play-services is not on Maven Central.
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev48-1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-google-api-client.txt'
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Logcat immediately after crashing by choosing my account from the account picker.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.googledrivetestapp, PID: 25164
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
        at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:267)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:292)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.example.googledrivetestapp.AsyncLoadTasks.doInBackground(AsyncLoadTasks.java:19)
        at com.example.googledrivetestapp.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:34)
        at com.example.googledrivetestapp.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:12)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Is there anyone out there that can end my misery?

Comment: Is there anyone on Earth who reads the logcat? `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null`

Comment: @Fantômas But WHY is it null?!  I'm not a professional programmer, I need help here.

Comment: Because you did not give it (or pass it) a value? It seems that currently `null = ""; // empty`.

Comment: Yeah I know what null is, I don't know why it's null in this case.  I understand if you can't work it out either.

Comment: It's not **null**. Or you would get a NullPointerException. It's **empty**. This is because you never assigned a value to it or (if it is a method parameter), you did not pass a a value to it. Or, the variable is *out of scope*: you think you valorized it in a class, but - in the class you're using it currently - the value remained unchanged to its default **empty** value.

Comment: So I guess the `public boolean equals(Object o)` line within the `android.accounts.Account` class is missing `Object o` whenever it is called?  I still don't know why though.

Comment: @Fantômas I'm only using what was in the official sample provided by Android.  Are you saying the official sample is wrong?  If so what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Download by link:
https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples.git

Open project "deprecation". This example will help access account. If you received your application credentials in the developer console: https://console.cloud.google.com